# VSTO Outlook: Apply a font to an Inbox view column

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a custom Inbox view, I mean, I have added a text column at the end.
Maybe I'm saying something stupid but now I would like to apply a ttf font to only this column, not to the rest of them. I am wondering if it is possible. If so, could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

The best what you could do is to use a conditional formatting for columns of the Outlook grid. Read more about that in the [Conditional formatting by Field Criteria with VBA (e.g. From address contains)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ac6113ca-4575-4f05-a7f7-ec2fb611b2cd/conditional-formatting-by-field-criteria-with-vba-eg-from-address-contains?forum=outlookdev) thread.

The [AutoFormatRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.AutoFormatRule) object represents a formatting rule used by a [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view) object to determine how to format Outlook items displayed within that view.

Formatting rules are checked and applied against each Outlook item, in the order in which they are contained within the `AutoFormatRules` collection. Use the `Enabled` property to enable or disable a formatting rule, the `Filter` property to define the conditions an Outlook item must meet to be formatted by the formatting rule, and the [Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.autoformatrule.font) property to specify the format to be applied by the formatting rule.

Comment: Yep, but is it possible to apply a different format for each column of the same grid row (and not for the entire column of the grid, only for the corresponding to that specific row) ? for example, Column A apply font Sans Serif with blue color, Column B apply font Courier New with red color, and so on. My rule would be to set a font for only a column (cell - specific column of a row-) if the Outlook mail item contains a particular custom property.